# Applying filters to Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

```
def show_category
  category_selected = params[:genre]
  all_movies = Movie.all
  @movies_in_category = all_movies.where(:category => category_selected)
  puts "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"
  puts category_selected
  puts @movies_by_category.length
end
```

I have the above controller function which gets called with a parameter.

```
params[:genre]
```

the above line print out the parameter just fine.

```
all_movies = Movie.all
@movies_in_category = all_movies.where(:category => category_selected)
```

But the above 2 lines of code don't seem to be executed at all (I don't see the SQL queries for the above 2 lines being printed on the Rails console.

I also tried this but still couldn't see the SQL on the Rails console:

```
@movies_in_category = Movie.where(:category => category_selected)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Note that something like `all_movies = Movie.all` or `all_movies.where(...)` will just instantiate a new `ActiveRecord::Relation` and not execute any query unless the records are actually accessed.

Comment: @ma_il thanks for your reply. However I DID try accessing `@movies_in_category` and tried to just print out all the movies in it inside a loop. But I got an error that `@movies_in_category` is `nil`!!  I have used filters quite a lot before but this time I am really confused

Comment: You're using both `@movies_in_category` and `@movies_by_category` here. Maybe just a spelling mistake?

Comment: My bad - it did turn out to be a spelling mistake. Thanks much!